# Spring MVC - request/process does not stop on logout

Tags: java, spring, session, logout

There is a process in our spring application which takes comparatively longer time. If we log out of the application in between the process, we see that the process is still running in the background. The classes that are running have the scope as session. Ideally, it should have stopped because the session is no longer valid. Can anyone throw some light?

I am attempting to make myself clearer:
Let's say that we have following class with session scope:

```
public class ExampleClass{

    private Class2 business;

    public entryFunction(){
        business = new Class2();
        business.function1();//takes around 10 mins
        business.function2());
        business.function3());
    }
}
```

Class2:

```
public class Class2 {

    public function1(){
        //Some complex process
    }

    public function2(){
        //Some functionality
    }

    public function3(){
    //Some functionality
    }

}
```

There is a function in Class2, function1 which takes around 10 mins because of it executing some complex scenario. Now, let's say when the function1 was under execution, the user logs out of the application. What we want is the execution should stop as soon as the person logs out/closes the browser or refreshes the page. So, in this case, function1() execution should stop in between and function2() and function3() should not be executed at all. What's happening as of now is that all the functions are being executed.
Please pardon me for the naming conventions. It's just for illustration of the problem and requirement.

Comment: Are you really sure that is the case and you aren't just seeing the scoped proxies instead of the actual objects. (I find your question largely hard to digest and unclear so maybe clarify things with images/samples/code).

Comment: All the classes used in the application have session scope. And we have not mentioned the proxy scope explicitly. And we can see the  process running in logs even if we log out in between. The main thing is that when we log out in between a process, the remaining process should not continue and should just end in between.

Comment: Then why are they session scoped? As mentioned make your question clearer then it is now. Also a preaches/thread that is started will not stop. So again (twice in one comment) please clarify your question with code/configuration etc.

Comment: I have attempted to make the requirement clearer.

Comment: "Also a preaches/thread that is started will not stop" I think this answers my question which means there is no way to stop the process in between. I have already given a code snippet to explain the problem. Please find it above.